# Difference between HandlerInterceptor and WebRequestInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

While writing interceptor for my application I noticed `HandlerInterceptor` and `WebRequestInterceptor` [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors).

I noticed that `HandlerInterceptor`'s method take `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, `Object`(handler) and other params
while `WebRequestInterceptor` take `WebRequest` (a wrapper of `HttpServletRequest`).

But I don't know what is the difference between these two interceptors.

Although seeing Spring API I can guess that `WebRequestInterceptor` can not commit response while `HandlerInterceptor` can do that. Please correct me here if I am wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With a `HandlerInterceptor` you can:

- Change the `HttpServletResponse` in `preHandle` method
- Apply filters based on `handler` object. For example, you can apply some filters based on presence of some annotations on `HandlerMethod`
- Prohibit the execution of the handler by returning `false` in `preHandle` method.

`HandlerInterceptor` can be used for a large field of preprocessing aspects, e.g. for authorization checks, or common handler behavior like locale, theme changes or adding `Cache-Control` headers. Its main purpose is to allow for factoring out repetitive handler code.

One of the canonical use cases of `WebRequestInterceptor` is preparing context resources (such as a Hibernate `Session`) and expose them as request attributes or as thread-local objects. Also, you can modify those context resources after successful handler execution (for example, flushing a Hibernate `Session`). For example, `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` binds a JPA `EntityManager` to the thread for the entire processing of the request.

> Although seeing Spring API I can guess that WebRequestInterceptor can
>   not commit response while HandlerInterceptor can do that. Please
>   correct me here if I am wrong.

`WebRequestInterceptor` interface is deliberately minimalistic to keep the dependencies of generic request interceptors as minimal as feasible. If you need to change the response, you should use `HandlerIntercepter` or `Filter`s.

Comment: Yes , I got this too here:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/class-use/WebRequestInterceptor.html . But I mean is it only for those purpose ?

Comment: And in `WebRequestInterceptor` you just can modify the model not response

Comment: Exactly that is what I am asking that's why it does not have any response parameter(**HttpServletResponse**) in its method signature

Comment: It's by design minimalistic, if you in need to change to response, use `HandlerIntercepter` or `Filter`.